# Is it possible to use store tags without it outputting a form element?

Tags: expresso-store

I'm in a situation on the cart/basket page where I want to use an embed, but, I want to use the checkout tag again within it, to work out some tax with php & then  add it to a table.

I've accomplished it fine, though it's adding a form element to the table element. 
Is there a param I'm missing where I can just say form_element="off" or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product tag allows you to add `disable_form="yes"` to remove the form tags.

Since you are trying to use the checkout tag however you best option would be to use the `{exp:store:cart}` tag pair for the nested content which is the exact same as the checkout tag but does not output a form tag.

> The Cart Tag behaves exactly the same as the Checkout Tag. The
>   difference lies in performance - while the Checkout Tag provides a
>   form, and provides options for updating and submitting the cart, the
>   Cart Tag simply displays a cached version of the current cart.
>
> You should use the Cart Tag instead of the Checkout Tag in sidebars
>   and headers, when you wish to display the contents of the current
>   cart.

Full documentation for the [cart tag](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/cart_tag.html) pair.